# ORACLE UTL_SMTP SMTP permanent error: 535 5.7.8

Tags: gmail, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I'm trying to send email with Oracle APEX 20.1, hence, I've configured the wallet with gmail certificates as I've done before, but now every time I attempt to send an email, always get the same response from google smtp servers:

```
SMTP permanent error: 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o40-20020a17090a0a2b00b001c77ebd8fa9sm275647pjo.17 - gsmtp
```

I've trippled check the account credentials, and the account security setting for untrusted apps is enabled.

Here's my procedure for sending email:

No 2 step verification is enabled.

At this point I'm really confused on what might been going on here.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEND_EMAIL(v_to varchar2, v_subject varchar2, v_mensaje varchar2) IS



 c utl_smtp.connection;
  l_mailhost    VARCHAR2 (64) := 'smtp.gmail.com';
  l_from        VARCHAR2(64) := 'test@test.com';
  l_from_alias  VARCHAR2 (64) := 'testa@test.com';
  l_to          VARCHAR2 (64) := v_to;
  l_subject     VARCHAR2 (64) := v_subject;
  l_conn    utl_smtp.connection;
  l_reply   utl_smtp.reply;
  crlf varchar2(2) := UTL_TCP.CRLF;
BEGIN

  c := utl_smtp.open_connection(
            host => l_mailhost,
            port => 587,
            wallet_path => 'file:/xxxxx/xxxxx',
            wallet_password => 'xxxxxxxx',
            secure_connection_before_smtp => false);
    dbms_output.put_line('utl_smtp.open_connection');

    --UTL_SMTP.EHLO(c, 'panamaensalarios.com');
    UTL_SMTP.EHLO(c, 'smtp.gmail.com');
    UTL_SMTP.starttls(c);

  dbms_output.put_line('Usuario : '|| utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( utl_encode.base64_encode( utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_from))));
  utl_smtp.command( c, 'AUTH LOGIN');
  utl_smtp.command( c, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( utl_encode.base64_encode( utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_from))));  
  utl_smtp.command( c, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( utl_encode.base64_encode( utl_raw.cast_to_raw([some_password]))));  
  



  UTL_SMTP.mail (c, l_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt (c, l_to);
  UTL_SMTP.open_data (c);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (c, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || crlf);
  --UTL_SMTP.write_data (c, 'From: ' || l_from_alias || crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (c, 'From: ' || l_from || crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (c, 'Subject: ' || l_subject || crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (c, 'To: ' || l_to || crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (c, '' || crlf);

 --FOR i IN 1 .. 10
 -- LOOP
 --   UTL_SMTP.write_data (c, 'This is a test message.' || TO_CHAR (i) || crlf);
 -- END LOOP;
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, v_mensaje || crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data (c);
  UTL_SMTP.quit (c); 
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  --UTL_SMTP.quit (c); 
     
  GP_AC_P_REGISTRA_LOG('PL','SEND_EMAIL',SYSDATE,USER,'E','error :'||SQLERRM);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR: '||SQLERRM);
  dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace );
END;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
Kind regards.